# Process.Start throws exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "The operation was canceled by the user" the first time it is started after login

Tags: c#, process, uac

We have created a deployment solution that checks for updates and starts a shortcut. Now i have a very strange behaviour. When i login to our RDS-Host (Windows Server 2019 Standard - 1809) the first time i start the tool it throws an exception at this line of code:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Users\dev.dmendez\AppData\Local\simplDeploy\packages\https!!!om-apps.com!csa!om_cs\furniture\12.10.2.0008\OM_CS.lnk");
```

It throws this exception and the process is not started:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "The operation was canceled by the user"

If i run it a second time the exception is not thrown and the process is started normaly. There is no UAC-Dialog poping up (UAC is activated). I've tried to change the target-Shortcut to require administrator-permission. With this setting active i get an UAC-Dialog and if cancel i get the exact same exception-message. It looks like windows somehow tries to start the shortcut as admin and automatically cancels the first time i run it after login.

I also tried Logon/Logout then run the target-shortcut manually before i run the program that also calls the shortcut and... No Exception!

Any ideas why i get this exception the first time i execute this line of code after login.

Comment: Does it happen if you execute the command line pointed to by the `lnk` file?

Comment: I checked it now. And yes it also happens

Comment: It would seem your executable is doing something intermittently that is triggering privilege escalation.

Comment: I seems so. Any ideas what could that be?

Comment: Microsoft has "appcompat" (application compatibility) resources and tools that may help you track this down.

Comment: Interesting tools (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install). Didn't help me for this issue, but definitely useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things and ended up with this:

```
try
{
    Process.Start(Manifest.GetExecutablePath());
}
catch (Win32Exception) // in some cases there happens an exception: "The operation was canceled by the user" on the first launch
{
    Process.Start(Manifest.GetExecutablePath());
}
```

I know it's nasty, but the exception reliable appears the first time after login and the second time it works perfectly, therefore i just ignore it one time and try again.